# Proof of Lambert azimuth equal-area projection from unit sphere Cartesian coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I'm looking into Wikipedia's [Lambert azimuthal equal-area projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_azimuthal_equal-area_projection), and found that the formula to project **Cartesian** coordinates back and forth are not what I discovered from the main idea described in the page, using the basic vector algebra. Maybe I did something wrong upon deriving from the idea.

How does this formula in the page come?

`(X,Y) = sqrt(2 / (1 - z)) * (x,y)`

and to inverse,

`(x,y,z) = (sqrt(1 - (X^2 + Y^2) / 4) * X, sqrt(1 - (X^2 + Y^2) / 4) * Y, -1 + (X^2 + Y^2) / 2)`

Could someone please prove them for me? It'd be nice if you also refer to the cross sectional view in the page upon proving.

Comment: By "back and forth", do you mean substituting $X$ and $Y$ from the first formula into the second formula?

Comment: @peterwhy yes, by projecting to the plane and reverting back to a sphere.

Comment: What did you get by back and forth using the basic vector algebra?